# Are Events in C# structs?

Tags: c#, events

So I have a dictionary of EventHandlers, yet I find that when I attach to an event before adding the keyvaluepair to the dictionary, everything works fine. But if I add the keyvaluepair and then update the value of the eventhandler, the dictionary does not update.

```
public static event EventHandler TestEvent;
private static Dictionary<int, EventHandler> EventMapping = new Dictionary<int, EventHandler>();

 //TestEvent += GTKWavePipeClient_TestEvent;

  EventMapping.Add(0, TestEvent);
  TestEvent += GTKWavePipeClient_TestEvent;
  //test event is non null now. keyvaluepair in EventMapping has a value of null
```

Comment: Could you post some example code that demonstrates the problem, so that we can try to reproduce it?

Comment: my question is poorly phased. I thought it was because of the static but it has nothing to do with that. I will rephrase it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delegate types like `EventHandler` are **immutable** types. When you use assignment (`=`) or compound assignment (`+=`), a new instance is created.

The dictionary holds on to the old instance.

Delegate types are reference types, but the important thing here is their immutability.

When you have an `event`, the use of the `+=` syntax is not even an assignment. It is an invocation of the `add` accessor or of the event. It will reassign the backing field (new instance) in a thread-safe way.

---

Remember that you can author your event accessors yourself. For example:

```
public static event EventHandler TestEvent
{
  add
  {
    lock (lockObj)
    {
      EventHandler oldDel;
      if (EventMapping.TryGetValue(0, out oldDel))
        EventMapping[0] = oldDel + value;
      else
        EventMapping.Add(0, value);
    }
  }

  remove
  {
    lock (lockObj)
    {
      EventHandler oldDel;
      if (EventMapping.TryGetValue(0, out oldDel))
        EventMapping[0] = oldDel - value;
    }
  }
}
private static readonly object lockObj = new object();
private static Dictionary<int, EventHandler> EventMapping = new Dictionary<int, EventHandler>();
```

With that code, when you go:

```
TestEvent += GTKWavePipeClient_TestEvent;
```

your `add` accessor is called with "implicit" parameter `EventHandler value` set to `GTKWavePipeClient_TestEvent`.

Comment: This isn't the first time I've seen overriding the assignment operator to add or remove events from a chain confusing people. I wish Microsoft had not done that.

Answer (score 4):

Delegates are immutable.  You are assigning a new object to TestEvent when invoking += to attach an event.  So in your non-working scenario, you have a different object within the Dictionary than the object which has the attached event.